# Need to generated OAuth token to open dialog

Tags: facebook, oauth, dialog, access-token, facebook-oauth

I am really struggling with this whole OAuth thing. I have a link that I want to pop open a dialog that will post a message to the user's wall. Here's my code...

```
<a href="https://graph.facebook.com/dustinmcgrew/feed?
link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
caption=Reference%20Documentation&
description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!"><img src="images/share.gif" /></a>
```

When I click the link it generates this error...

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

How do I get this access token and is there anything I need to do with it after I get it? The Facebook documentation is really pissing me off. It gives you sample code that only does half of what it needs to do IMO.

I am using the PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Facebook's Dialogs documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/):

> Every dialog has a method name and parameters. The URL to a dialog always starts with `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/` followed by the name of the dialog and parameters.

The reason you are being asked for an OAuth access token is because [Facebook thinks you are trying to access your wall](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed), which is located at `https://graph.facebook.com/dustinmcgrew/feed`.

Getting an OAuth token (which you will need to understand if you are building a Facebook application) is covered in the [Authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). The PHP SDK also provides methods (like [getAccessToken](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/) to make this process easier.

Comment: I tried that portion of the url you gave me and I get this error.. 

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: dialog",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}`

Comment: It should be http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed not https://graph.facebook.com/dialog/feed. Your URL is also missing the redirect_uri parameter. You should probably read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/, especially the "Direct URL Example" section.

Comment: Ok I have that url in now but now it sends me to a login page with a facebook logo on it. After I click Go to facebook.com the dialog appears. Grrr :(

Comment: You really should have made a new question (since this is a completely different issue), but try changing the display parameter (described in the "Display Modes" section of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/